# 2 POCO's with inheritance creates one table instead of two

Tags: c#, inheritance, ef-code-first

I am creating a fairly simplistic `Database` for a holiday system.

**Entities**

`Employee`

```
public class Employee
{
  public int Id { get; set;}
  public string Username { get; set; }
  public LineManger Manager { get; set; }
}
```

`LineManger`

```
public class LineManager : Employee
{
  public string CompanySection { get; set; }
}
```

**Relationship**

As you can see, each employee has one `LineManger` however an `Employee` could be a `LineManager`.

In my `DbContext` I have:

```
public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
public DbSet<LineManager> Managers { get; set; }
public DbSet<HolidayConfiguration> Configurations { get; set; }
public DbSet<Holiday> Holidays { get; set; }
```

When I ran `PM > Update-Database -verbose` for the first time it only created an `Employee` table and this table has `CompanySection` and `Manager_Id` which doesn't map to anywhere seeing as there isn't a `LineManager` table.

Any explanations on why this has happened? Is this correct?

Comment: You're using defaults. Assign  table-names (attribute or fluent notation).

Comment: You're using inheritance. The characteristic you have discovered is not a problem. But what could be a problem is that your POCO model won't support changing an Employee to be a LineManager or not be a LineManager.

Comment: @TomBlodget so in this case, would it be better too take the normalization down a level and have a `IsLineManager` atrribute and a `CompanySection` attribute all in employee?

Comment: I take it from your question about normalization that it wouldn't make sense for every employee to have a company section.  In that case, perhaps a company section should be an entity and have the attribute of an employee that is its line manager. BTW @Garath answered your original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be like this, because every LineManager is an Employee, so when you are querying Employees you are also looking for LineManager. `DbSet<Employee> Employees` matches only one table, so the only way how EF can create table is to put in it all fields from LineManager.

Sometime (when you have more inhertiance) EF create special column in which it puts class name.